# Convert to template

Tags: c++

I'm wondering how can i do something like this ? Using `template<typename T>` with `typedef` ?

```
template <typename T>
typedef bool (*cmp_func)(T i0, T i1); // <- syntax error here
```

I'm trying to sort items of a template type.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

typedef bool (*cmp_func)(int i0, int i1);


template<typename T>
void print_array(int n, T *x)
{
        cout << "[";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                cout << setw(3) << x[i];
        }
        cout << " ]\n";
 }

template <typename T>
bool less_than(T i0, T i1) { return i0 < i1; }

template <typename T>
bool greater_than(T i0, T i1) { return i0 > i1; }

template <typename T>
bool is_sorted(int n, T *x, cmp_func cmp)
{
        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
                if ((*cmp)(x[i], x[i-1]))
                        return false;

        return true;
}  

  template <typename T>
void exchange(T* x, int i, int j)
{
        T t = x[i];
        x[i] = x[j];
        x[j] = t;
}


template <typename T>
void insertion_sort(T *x, int l, int r, cmp_func cmp)
{
        for (int i = l+1; i <= r; ++i) {
                for (int j = i; j > l; --j){
                        if ((*cmp)(x[j], x[j-1]))
                                exchange(x, j, j-1);
                    cout << "  ";
                    print_array(r-l+1, x+l);
                }
        }
}

template <typename T>
void insertion_sort2(T *x, int l, int r, cmp_func cmp)
{
        for (int i = r; i > l; --i)
                if ((*cmp)(x[i], x[i-1]))
                        exchange(x, i, i-1);

        for (int i = l+2; i <= r; ++i) {
                int j = i;
                int v = x[i];
                while((*cmp)(v, x[j-1])) {
                        x[j] = x[j-1];
                        --j;
                }
                x[j] = v;

                cout << "  ";
                print_array(r-l+1, x+l);
        }
}

template <typename T>
void fill_random(T n, T *x)
{
        const int M = 100;

        srand(time(0));

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                x[i] = rand() % M;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        const int N = 10;
        int x[N];
        fill_random(N, x);
        print_array(N, x);

        insertion_sort(x, 0, N-1, &less_than);
        print_array(N, x);

        if (is_sorted(N, x, &less_than))
                cout << "SORTED\n";
        else
                cout << "NOT SORTED\n";

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Please don't remove your question after receiving an answer; even if you have your answer, the question and answer can still be useful to others in the future.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Typedefs cannot be templates.  C++11 `using` aliases, however, can be:

```
template <typename T>
using cmp_func = bool (*)(T i0, T i1);
```

The pre-C++11 workaround is to create a template struct that has a `type` typedef:

```
template <typename T>
struct cmp_func {
    typedef bool (*type)(T i0, T i1);
};
```

Which is then referenced as `typename cmp_func<int>::type` for example.

Comment: Well thanks but when i try to write your first solution i get error. Firstly "error: expected unqualified-id before 'using' 
then " 'cmp_func' has not been declared "

Comment: @KaanCaglan It compiles fine for me. Are you compiling in C++11 (or higher) mode?

Comment: @KaanCaglan Also, consider using a template parameter for the comparer and then this problem goes away entirely: `template <typename T, typename U> bool is_sorted(int n, T *x, U && cmp)`. Then the type of the compare function can be deduced and you don't even need a named `cmp_func` at all. Plus you get the ability to use functors instead of function pointers, you can use `std::function`, etc.

Comment: Actually i don't know  :D im using Notepad++ in win8 and emacs in linux